# Tensorflow Tensorboard on Windows shows a blank page

Tags: tensorflow, spyder, tensorboard

I'm using Tensorflow on Windows but when I try to launch Tensorboard opening `http://localhost:6006` the browser shows a blank page

I have added the codeline
`writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('mypath/my_graph', sess.graph)`

to my Tensorflow model and launched tensorboard with
`tensorboard --logdir="mypath/my_graph"`

Here the console output:

[image]

Following mrry suggestion I have updated to 0.12.0rc1 and now the Tensorboard page is shown but unfortunately I cannot see any graph, and is missing also the left panel to upload a graph file manually that I can see  in some screenshots of the official guide.

[image]

Tried also to use

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('mypath/my_graph', sess.graph)
```

following the deprecation hint

**EDIT**

I have found the problem. If I launch `tensorboard --logdir="mypath/my_graph"` TensorBoard is unable to load the path and looks always for the graph files in the default user path `C:\Users\andrew\mygraph\` if I run console as user or `C:\Windows\System32` if I run console as administrator. This is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? 0.12.0rc0 has a known issue, but it should be fixed in 0.12.0rc1.

Comment: I use exactly the version 0.12.0 rc0

Comment: Is there anything in the log file that you wrote using `writer`? A common error is to exit without calling `writer.close()` or `writer.flush()`.

Comment: @mrry The write doesn't show any error message. I have added `writer.flush and writer.close()` and I can see the the folder `my_gaph` with `events.out.tfevents.somecode` file in the path chosen for the file writer. Is there any way to see in what path TensorBoard is looking for the graph file or load the graph file manually from TensorBoard?

Comment: @mrry I have found the problem. If I launch `tensorboard --logdir="mypath/my_graph"` TensorBoard is unable to load the path and looks always for the graph files in the default user path. This is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the problem! Please do open a GitHub issue with details of how to reproduce the problem, and somebody on the team will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The `0.12.0rc0` (Release Candidate 0) release of TensorFlow on Windows contains a broken version of TensorBoard. We recently made a new release (`0.12.0rc1`, Release Candidate 1) that contains a fix for TensorBoard on Windows. You can upgrade by following the [instructions for installing the latest release on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows), or simply typing `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` at the command prompt.

Comment: I have updated and now I can see TensorBoard page, but Tensor Board seems unable to find my graph definition files . See the updated question.

Comment: If your summaries are in, e.g. "E:\tf\summaries", start cmd in windows, then run "E:", then "tensorboard --logdir=\tf\summaries"

Answer (score 0):

In **ubuntu** we can use:

tensorboard --logdir=/home/user/graph/

In **Windows** we have to change the command prompt to the directory in which the graph file is placed and then use:

tensorboard --logdir=\home\user\graph\